# inArray values issue

Tags: jquery, arrays

```
    var checkboxarray = $.makeArray(data.checkboxes);

    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    var chckval = $(this).val();
    var verifyvalue = $.inArray(chckval, checkboxarray);

    if(verifyvalue != -1){
    $(this).attr('checked',true);
    }
 });
```

//Array value of data.checkboxes
[Inclusion 1, Inclusion 2, Inclusion 3, What to bring 1, What to bring 2, What to bring 3, What to bring 4, Requirement 1, Requirement 2, Requirement 3, Requirement 4]

//Issue
I set up checkboxes manually to match all contained in the array 'checkboxarray', the first value always returns 0, but after that returns -1 not even if there are values that matches in both sides.

Any ideas?

Comment: could you give a dump of `checkboxarray`

Comment: Retagged -javascript +jquery. Since this isn't about ECMAScript at all, just the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

It's working just [fine](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/5ZDNE/), just make sure your `checkboxarray` array contains a set of "*strings*".

Answer (score 0):

Wierd,
These are my testing checkboxes values:
value="Inclusion 1"
value="Inclusion 2"
value="Inclusion 3"
value="Inclusion 4"
value="What to bring 1"
value="What to bring 2"
value="What to bring 3"
value="What to bring 4"
value="Requirement 1"
value="Requirement 2"
value="Requirement 3"
value="Requirement 4"

This is a dump of checkboxarray:
Inclusion 1, Inclusion 2, What to bring 1, What to bring 2, What to bring 3, What to bring 4, Requirement 1, Requirement 2, Requirement 3, Requirement 4

When I call the function only "Inclusion 1" gets checked, the rest keeps unchecked, such a tiny script is making me nuts hahaha... any help?

Comment: infaour, your comment got my attention about "strings"... as you can see my "checkboxarray" dump each item comes with no quotes "", could be that the issue?

Comment: To Admin: This is my first time in stack, I posted a comment as an answer, it will not happen again... sorry.

Comment: Im posting the full function, the url however is not real:

Comment: @Xerrano: just add those as comment to my answer and delete yours ;-)

Comment: @Xerrano: and YES this is the issue!

Comment: Thank you, let check that up... I gues I'll need to re-format my output from coldfusion... :) Thanks again, let play a little with that tip of yours!

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to your tip and feed back Ifaour, I think I found the problem, here it is, in case someone runs with a similar situation:

The problem was in my database, my records were as follows:
*Requirement 1, Requirement 2, Requirement 3, Requirement 4*, 
The Dump for such:
*[{"value":" Requirement 1"},{"value":" Requirement 2"},{"value":" Requirement 3"},{"value":" Requirement 4"}]*
See the problem? **" Requirement 1"** the space **" R.....** between the first quote and the "R"
The script was looking for **"Option 1"** the database had **" Option 1"**
Thank you **Ifaour**